# How should I return dictionary one by one from list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list

```
list = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
          'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
          'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
          'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
          'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
          
          {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
           'Clear': DONE,
          'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
          'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
          'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
          'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
```

In  that list there is two dictionary and want to return those dictionaries one by one to other function of python, so what should I do?

**I tried:**

```
def data():
    iData = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
              
              {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
               'Clear': DONE,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]

    

    for i in iData:
        return i

def return_data():
    i = data()
    print("returned i", i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_data()
```

But when return statement hits, code come out of function, and returns only one dictionary, I want to return that both dictionaries one by one and need to do some operations in `return_data()` function.

Comment: You should do your operations in the function and return the result. `return` will **exit** the function when it is called.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "one by one". Why not just return the list (`return iData`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use yield instead of return.

```
def data():
     iData = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': 'F', 'Clear': None,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
              {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': 'F', 
               'Clear': 'DONE',
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]

    

        for i in iData:
            yield i

   if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = data()
    print(next(result))
    print(next(result))
```

You can read more about generator at [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), or check python docs on Genarator

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yield` instead of `return` to create a generator object that contains the dictionaries

```
def data():
    iData = [{...}, {...}]

    for i in iData:
        yield i

def return_data():
    i = data()
    for x in i:
        print("returned i", x)
```

Output:

```
# returned i {'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': 'F', 'Clear': None, 'Computed': None, 'impact': 0, 'Status': 'NOT', 'ID': None, 'bel': None, 'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257, 'Name': 'xyz'}
# returned i {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': 'F', 'Clear': 'DONE', 'Computed': None, 'impact': 234, 'Status': 'NOT', 'ID': None, 'bel': None, 'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650, 'Name': 'xyz'}
```

As a side note, you can't have a duplicate key ('Status') in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options that I know.
First, try this

**Example1**

```
def data():
    return [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
              
              {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
               'Clear': DONE,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]

def return_data():
    i = data()
    print(f"returned i {[i[0],i[1]]}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_data()
```

This above will return the list of dicts and you can use indexing to take each one.

**Example2**

```
def data():
    iData = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
              
              {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
               'Clear': DONE,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]

    for i in iData:
        print(i)

def return_data():
    i = data()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_data()
```

Or you don't use return and instead use print.

**Example3**

Or you can call return data twice

```
def data():
    iData = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
              
              {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
               'Clear': DONE,
              'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
              'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
              'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
              'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]

    for i in iData:
        return return_data(i)

def return_data():
    i = data()
    print(f'data {i}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop in the function `data()` you return `i` for every `i` in `iData`, the issue with this is that after the first pass the function returns and exits.

I would recommend moving the `return`.